# Magnetic field in a copper pipe carrying current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A copper pipe carries current I and the question asks if there is a magnetic field inside the pipe this is done by Ampere's law and equating the line integral to zero since the enclosed current in a loop is zero.

But this does not prove that the magnetic field can be perpendicular to the loop (i.e along the pipe). How can this be shown ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't prove that, but it does prove that any such field is nothing to do with the current. It could be the Earth's magnetic field or some other stray field, but it's not generated by the current.

Comment: What's your opinion on rabbits?